# How to get Popup after 3 page

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, html, design

Actually, i want popup after 3 page, not on the first page and this is my code;
This is simple HTML code in which you can see the output by making HTML file on the desktop.

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>jQuery Cookie Based jQuery Popup Window</title>
  <style>

body { background: lightyellow; }

#active-popup {
  background-color: rgba(52,73,94, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  heighT: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

#popup-container {
  width: 45%;
  height: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 28%;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  background: #E74C3C;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#popup-window { position: relative; }

.modal-content h1,
.modal-content p { color: #fff; }

.modal-content p { padding: 20% 5% 0 5%; }

#popup-container a.close {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: -15px;
  right: -7px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 6px;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:#fff;
}
  </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header id="header">
  </header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <div id="popup-container">
        <a class="close">X</a>
          <div id="popup-window">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <a href="#" class="your-class"></a>
            <h1>jQuery Cookie Based jQuery Popup Window</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam luctus ultrices velit sed finibus. Aenean id ex commodo, dapibus turpis tincidunt, bibendum ante.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    /*!
 * jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.0
 * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Klaus Hartl
 * Released under the MIT license
 */
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals.
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {

    var pluses = /\+/g;

    function encode(s) {
        return config.raw ? s : encodeURIComponent(s);
    }

    function decode(s) {
        return config.raw ? s : decodeURIComponent(s);
    }

    function stringifyCookieValue(value) {
        return encode(config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value));
    }

    function parseCookieValue(s) {
        if (s.indexOf('"') === 0) {
            // This is a quoted cookie as according to RFC2068, unescape...
            s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
        }

        try {
            // Replace server-side written pluses with spaces.
            // If we can't decode the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
            // If we can't parse the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
            s = decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
            return config.json ? JSON.parse(s) : s;
        } catch(e) {}
    }

    function read(s, converter) {
        var value = config.raw ? s : parseCookieValue(s);
        return $.isFunction(converter) ? converter(value) : value;
    }

    var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

        // Write

        if (value !== undefined && !$.isFunction(value)) {
            options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);

            if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                var days = options.expires,
                t = options.expires = new Date();
                t.setTime(+t + days * 864e+5);
            }

            return (document.cookie = [
                encode(key), '=', stringifyCookieValue(value),
                options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
                options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
                options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
            ].join(''));
        }

        // Read

        var result = key ? undefined : {};

        // To prevent the for loop in the first place assign an empty array
        // in case there are no cookies at all. Also prevents odd result when
        // calling $.cookie().
        var cookies = document.cookie ? document.cookie.split('; ') : [];

        for (var i = 0, l = cookies.length; i < l; i++) {
            var parts = cookies[i].split('=');
            var name = decode(parts.shift());
            var cookie = parts.join('=');

            if (key && key === name) {
                // If second argument (value) is a function it's a converter...
                result = read(cookie, value);
                break;
            }

            // Prevent storing a cookie that we couldn't decode.
            if (!key && (cookie = read(cookie)) !== undefined) {
                result[name] = cookie;
            }
        }

        return result;
    };

    config.defaults = {};

    $.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
        if ($.cookie(key) === undefined) {
            return false;
        }

        // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
        $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
        return !$.cookie(key);
    };

}));
    </script>
    <script>
        ////SCRIPT FOR MODAL POPUP WINDOW

jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('#popup-container a.close').click(function(){
            jQuery('#popup-container').fadeOut();
            jQuery('#active-popup').fadeOut();
    });

    var visits = jQuery.cookie('visits') || 0;
    visits++;

    jQuery.cookie('visits', visits, { expires: 1, path: '/' });

    console.debug(jQuery.cookie('visits'));

    if ( jQuery.cookie('visits') > 1 ) {
        jQuery('#active-popup').hide();
        jQuery('#popup-container').hide();
    } else {
            var pageHeight = jQuery(document).height();
            jQuery('<div id="active-popup"></div>').insertBefore('body');
            jQuery('#active-popup').css("height", pageHeight);
            jQuery('#popup-container').show();
    }

    if (jQuery.cookie('noShowWelcome')) { jQuery('#popup-container').hide(); jQuery('#active-popup').hide(); }
}); 

jQuery(document).mouseup(function(e){
    var container = jQuery('#popup-container');

    if( !container.is(e.target)&& container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.fadeOut();
        jQuery('#active-popup').fadeOut();
    }

});
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by after 3 page. You need popup on product page or you need popup after customer visit any 3 page of site

Comment: you can do with the help of session.

Comment: no, i didn't want pop up 3rd time I want popup on 3rd page @vaibhavahalpara

Comment: I did not understand , what do you mean by 3rd page?can you please explain more about 3rd page

Comment: when customer come on homepage after he visit 1st page than 2nd page and than 3rd page and at that time my popup want to be open

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please be specific with the 3rd page is it any custom page , category /product listing or product view or any other page.

Comment: whenever user open any 3 pages than after on the fourth page i want my popup.